# How to graph a median and IC 95%

Tags: r, confidence-interval, data-visualization, median, ggplot2

I Just need to build a graph with a median and its 95% confidence interval and I just can't do it. Here is my code where I set up the data.

```
library(ggplot2)
setwd('C:/Documents and Settings/usuario/Mis documentos/Martin/Midazolam/')
dat <- read.table (file='sim008', skip=1, header=T)
ggplot (dat) +
  geom_point (aes(x=TIME, y=IPRED),  colour='darkblue') +
  xlab('TIME') +
  ylab('IPRED')
```

[image]

Comment: Did you try with geom_errorbar ?

Comment: No I did not. I tried stat_summary(fun.y = median, fun.ymin = median, fun.ymax = median,
                 geom = "crossbar", width = 0.5)

Comment: I advise you to look at geom_errorbar

Comment: Wouldn't `geom_smooth()` work ?

Comment: I will try geom_smooth again and see what happen

Comment: I m still stucked if someone can write a similar code in which i can work on i will apreciate it!

Comment: You shoud consider giving [a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). We do not have your data, it is difficult to help.

Answer (score 0):

Time    (0  0   0.083333    0.083333    0.16667 0.16667 0.25    0.25    0.5 0.5 0.75    0.75    1   1   1.5 1.5 2   2   3   3   4   4   5   5   6   6   8   8   0   0   0.083333    0.083333    0.16667 0.16667 0.25    0.25    0.5 0.5 0.75    0.75    1   1   1.5 1.5 2   2   3   3   4   4   5   5   6   6   8   8   10  10  0   0   0.083333    0.083333    0.16667 0.16667 0.25    0.25    0.5 0.5 0.75    0.75    1   1   1.5 1.5 2   2   3   3   4   4   5   5   6   6   8   8   10  10  12  12  0   0   0.083333    0.083333    0.16667 0.16667 0.25    0.25    0.5 0.5 0.75    0.75    1   1   1.5 1.5 2   2   3   3   4   4   5   5   6   6   8   8   10  10  0   0   0.083333    0.083333    0.16667 0.16667 0.25    0.25    0.5 0.5 0.75    0.75    1   1   1.5 1.5 2   2   3   3   4   4   5   5   6   6   8   8   10  10  12  12  0   0   0.083333    0.083333    0.16667 0.16667 0.25    0.25    0.5 0.5 0.75    0.75    1   1   1.5 1.5 2   2   3   3   4   4   5   5   6   6   8   8   10  10  12  12)
IPRED   (256.13 256.13  226.52  226.52  201.33  201.33  179.84  179.84  132.07  132.07  101.21  101.21  80.505  80.505  55.393  55.393  40.846  40.846  24.207  24.207  14.95   14.95   9.4592  9.4592  6.1677  6.1677  2.9928  2.9928  330.05  330.05  295.35  295.35  265.46  265.46  239.64  239.64  180.9   180.9   141.58  141.58  114.31  114.31  79.893  79.893  59.158  59.158  34.802  34.802  20.998  20.998  12.704  12.704  7.6906  7.6906  2.8676  2.8676  1.1531  1.1531  249.85  249.85  223.88  223.88  201.95  201.95  183.4   183.4   142.94  142.94  117.77  117.77  101.64  101.64  83.392  83.392  73.563  73.563  62.033  62.033  54.066  54.066  47.606  47.606  42.111  42.111  33.158  33.158  26.197  26.197  20.722  20.722  192.4   192.4   169.61  169.61  150.44  150.44  134.3   134.3   99.382  99.382  77.87   77.87   64.166  64.166  48.662  48.662  40.235  40.235  30.312  30.312  23.726  23.726  18.767  18.767  14.91   14.91   9.4676  9.4676  6.0325  6.0325  329.82  329.82  232.03  232.03  174.84  174.84  141.18  141.18  101.57  101.57  91.037  91.037  86.209  86.209  79.156  79.156  72.679  72.679  60.707  60.707  50.199  50.199  41.214  41.214  33.671  33.671  22.274  22.274  14.641  14.641  9.5963  9.5963  294.19  294.19  271.48  271.48  251.42  251.42  233.67  233.67  191.36  191.36  160.92  160.92  138.34  138.34  107.29  107.29  86.714  86.714  60.159  60.159  43.426  43.426  32.246  32.246  24.64   24.64   15.725  15.725  11.143  11.143  8.4898  8.4898)

There I have the data